# PDO fetch object key value as id and keep the id in the object

Tags: php, pdo

I have looked around alot with this problem. I want to get a array of my objects and the id should be the key value. I did this using the PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE.

It almost worked the way I want to. Problem here is that the ID will be removed from the object and will only show as the key value. But I want the key value as the id value AND KEEP the id attached to the object.

I tried this myself

```
$getUsers->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, User\Basic::class);
```

This does return the id, but the id is everywhere 0.

concept:

```
{
   id: 3,
   name: 'pietje'
},
{
   id: 4,
   name: 'pietje'
}
```

Then i want a array of object like this (I think I made a mistake here)

```
[3 => {
       id: 3,
       name: 'pietje'
     }, 
 4=> {
       id: 4,
       name: 'pietje'

}]
```

But like i sayed, the id in the object is always 0the way I did it, and i could not find anything on the internet about the way I want it. Yhea sure I can loop every user and add a id, but then I can just loop through every user and create a new array with the user id as key value.

Any one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select your field twice,

```
SELECT id, table.* FROM table ...
```

Comment: Holy molly. Most simple and legit way. This is like a facepalm moment. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

PDO::FETCH_GROUP will allow you to group results; since you are grouping by id and should be unique you will get all rows as needed.
EDIT:

```
$sth = $pdo_dbh->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM users');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = array_map('reset', $result);
```

will return array like this.

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Rob
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => George
    )
)
```

it helps move ID column as keys in result array, and only keeps desired columns in array values. I fail to notice you wish to fetch results as class object.
Unnecessary nesting removed with array_map.

Comment: it will add another nesting level to the resulting array which is quite inconvenient

Comment: And the ids are still 0.